# Buffalo Linkstation NAS (LS-CHL) died, trying to recover data from disk

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, raid, data-recovery

I have infamous Buffalo Linkstation (LS-CHL) NAS which had one 500GT disk in it. And one day it started to flash red lights and not responding over the net. I tried to put it in different "recovery modes" that it provides, but it didn't help.

I have some files in the disk that i would want to keep (I'd copy them to some cloud service..), thus I opened the box and inserted the disk inside of my PC and booted to Live Ubuntu to check it out.

When looked at with fdisk, the disk looks like that: [image: fdisk_screenshot]

/dev/sdb2 is mountable and it has operating system on it. If files are still intact, they should live on /dev/sdb6. What means *extended* on /dev/sdb4?

*gparted* do not identify filesystem on partition sdb6. I have tried to mount it anyways as ufs partition, without any luck

```
  ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mount -t ufs /dev/sdb6 /mnt/recovery/
  mount: /dev/sdb6 is write-protected, mounting read-only
  mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb6,
  missing codepage or helper program, or other error

  In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
  dmesg | tail or so.
```

I have also tried to mount it with regular mounting options (ext2,3,4, auto), without any success.

What else could I try? UFSexplorer in Windows didn't find anything on that, which was not promising..

When trying to mount as UFS, dmesg says here this:

```
[ 5563.031225] ufs: ufs_fill_super(): bad magic number
```

I have googled around for few days and tested all ideas with raid. That's the second possibility that even if there is only one partition, it is a raid0 partition or something and thats why regular tools wont understand it.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb6
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb6.
```

Yet it would not seem to be the case. Or is it, but superblock is just broken?

When using that same command against sdb4, it gave me something:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb4
/dev/sdb4:    
MBR Magic : aa55 
Partition[0] :      2008062 sectors at     63 (type 82) 
Partition[1] :    960960105 sectors at      2008125 (type 05)
```

Yet I dont know what that means or does it help me at all. Other examples that i've seen in the internet do not show such answers but a lot more informative ones.

Can you suggest me things that i should try? Do somebody know better Linkstations innerworkings and thus know what this is all about? Am I dealing with a broken raid, or maybe a broken filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

The FS is SGI XFS. Try to use any data recovery software and examine your disk. I'm using [UFS Explorer Standard Recovery](https://www.ufsexplorer.com/download.php#tab-std).